# Getting all images from a webpage and save the to disk programmatically (NodeJS & Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I need to get a lot of images from a few websites and download them to my disk so that I can use them (will upload them to a blob (azure) and then save the link to my DB).

### GETTING THE IMAGES

I know how to get the images from the html with JS, for example one of them I would make a for-loop and do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('person')[i].querySelector('div').querySelector('img').getAttribute('src')
```

And there I would have the links to all the images.

### SAVING THE IMAGES

I also saw that I can save the files to disk using node and the fs module, by doing:

```
function saveImageToDisk(url, localPath) {var fullUrl = url;
var file = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);
var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
response.pipe(file);
});
```

}

### HOW TO PUT IT ALL TOGETHER

This is where I am stuck, I don't know exactly how to connect the two parts (the script and the nodejs code), I want to get the image and also the image name (alt tag in this case) and then use them in node to upload the image to a blob and put them name and image blob url in my DB.

I thought I could download the html page and then put the JS script on the bottom of the body but then I don't know how to pass the url to the nodejs code.

How can I do this?

I am not very used to using scripts, I mostly used node without them and I get a bit confused by their interactions and how to connect js scripts to my code.

Also is this the best way to go about this or is there a simpler/better way I am not seeing?

Comment: Take a look at Google's Puppeteer, with it you can access and take data from a website via node https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Use ajax to send the url array from client to node server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like you should use a crawler. The following code should work (using the npm module [crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler)):

```js
const Crawler = require("crawler")

const c = new Crawler({
    callback: function(error, res, done) {
        if (error) {
            console.log({error})
        } else {
            const images = res.$('.person div img')
            images.each(index => {
                // here you can save the file or save them in an array to download them later
                console.log({
                    src: images[index].attribs.src,
                    alt: images[index].attribs.alt,
                })
            })
        }
    }
})

c.queue('https://www.yoursite.com')
```

Comment: Thanks very much I was really blown away by all the great answers on this post, I did at the end go with Crawler cause it seemed very easy to implement. Is the crawler npm still being maintained? is it likely to be around in the future?

Comment: @Jack I don't know. Honestly, I've never used a node-based crawler. I just googled for one and then made this small demo. However, since it still gets a lot of weekly downloads and the last commits weren't to far back, it seems safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need a bridge between Web API (for DOM parsing etc) and Node.js API. For example, some headless browser managing tool for Node.js. Say, you can use [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) with this script:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image');

    const imgURLs = await page.evaluate(() =>
      Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('#mw-content-text img.thumbimage'),
        ({ src }) => src,
      )
    );
    console.log(imgURLs);
    await browser.close();

    imgURLs.forEach((imgURL, i) => {
      https.get(imgURL, (response) => {
        response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${i++}.${imgURL.slice(-3)}`));
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

You can even download images just once, using pictures already downloaded by the browser. This script saves identical images, but with one session of requests, without using `https` Node.js module (this saves time, network traffic and server workload):

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    const allImgResponses = {};
    page.on('response', (response) => {
      if (response.request().resourceType() === 'image') {
        allImgResponses[response.url()] = response;
      }
    });

    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image');

    const selecedImgURLs = await page.evaluate(() =>
      Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('#mw-content-text img.thumbimage'),
        ({ src }) => src,
      )
    );
    console.log(selecedImgURLs);

    let i = 0;
    for (const imgURL of selecedImgURLs) {
      fs.writeFileSync(
        `${i++}.${imgURL.slice(-3)}`,
        await allImgResponses[imgURL].buffer(),
      );
    }

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I've added a more efficient way.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for this answer. I was blown away from all the answers on this post. I went with the crawler option though, Pupetteer definitely seems like the more popular and more used package, but other than your post I wasn't able to find any info on how to do this with pupetter quickly since I wanted to do it a bit diferently.  I will definitely take a further look into pupeteer and try to learn it well and implement it. Thank you very much for this info!

Comment: @Jack Thank you and happy coding)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the `dom-parser` module. See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser

By doing so, you can download the whole html-File with `http.get()` and parse it using the `dom-parser`. Then extract all the information you need from the HTML-File. With the Image URL, use your `saveImageToDisk()` function.

Following your idea, you have to add the JS script to the html-File as you mentioned. But in addition you have to use Ajax (`xmlHttpRequest`) to post the URL to a nodeJS-Server.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the great answer, I was blown away from all the great answers and options for this, I went this time with crawler because i felt it might be a bit more efficient but thank you very much for opening my eyes to dom-parser, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise` & inside it do the job of getting all the images and put the image url in an array.Then inside the then method you can either iterate the array and call the `saveImageToDisk` each time or you can send the array to the middle layer with slide modification. The second option is better since it will make only one network call

```js
function getImages() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // Array.from will create an array
     // map will return a new array with all the image url
    let k = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('person')[0].querySelector('div')
        .querySelectorAll('img'))
      .map((item) => {
        return item.getAttribute('src')
      })
    resolve(k)
  })
}
getImages().then((d) => {
 // it will work only after the promise is resolved
  console.log('****', d);
  (item => {
    // call saveImageToDisk function

  })

})

function saveImageToDisk(url, localPath) {
  var fullUrl = url;
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);
  var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
  });
```

```html
<div class='person'>
  <div>
    <img src='https://www.fast-growing-trees.com/images/P/Leyland-Cypress-450-MAIN.jpg'>
    <img src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2473/3486/products/Cypress_Leyland_2_Horticopia_d1b5b63a-8bf7-4897-96fb-05320bf3d81b_grande.jpg?v=1532991076'>
    <img src='https://www.fast-growing-trees.com/images/P/Live-Oak-Tree-450w.jpg'>
    <img src='https://www.greatgardenplants.com/images/uploads/452_1262_popup.jpg'>
    <img src='https://shop.arborday.org/data/default/images/catalog/600/Turnkey/1/Leyland-Cypress_3-828.jpg'>


    <img src='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RZkKnrlSL._SX425_.jpg'>

    <img src='https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/Z3JYiuJ96ReLq04NCT1B94sTd4E=/800x600/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/06/9c/069cfb16-c46c-4742-85f0-3c7e45fa139d/mar2018_a05_talkingtrees.jpg'>


  </div>
```

Comment: Can I only run this in the browser console or can I somehow run it in my node app so that I can send the images and the name from the alt tag to my DB???